# cin.get() not blocking

Tags: c++, windows

i have been trying to figure this out for about 2 hours. whatever i do, cin.get() does not pause my program. even the simplest programs. like this,

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    cout << "Hello World! ";
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

what is wrong with this??
i have tried many things like making more cin.get'S or even system pauses. ive switched things around and nothing works. please help!

Comment: Works for me on WinXP with MSVC++ 2009.  I think the mistake must be elsewhere.  What compiler are you using?

Comment: Are you redirecting input from a file or piping it in from another process?

Comment: How are you running your program?  What happens when you run it from the command line?  What about double-clicking on its icon?

Comment: @random_hacker i am using visual c++ to compile

Comment: @j_random_hacker i am using visual c++ to compile

Comment: Are you compiling the Debug version but running the Release version, or vice versa?  Sometimes when I find that nothing I do seems to make any difference, the problem turns out to be this :)

Comment: Try creating a win32 console application. That might help...